# With NodeJS, How To execute a series of node installs

Tags: node.js

I've got  a file (like below) that has a list of npm install commands. I was hoping I could do

```
npm < files.txt
```

to get it to run those but that does not work.  How can I install all these packages? I hate to put them all on one big line.

```
npm install angular  angular-ui-router --save
npm install angular  watchify browser-sync --save
npm install angular-mocks --save
npm install angular-sanitize --save 
....
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a `package.json` instead?

Comment: My thinking was if I do these npm commands that will add it to my package.json file with all the correct syntax.

Comment: Assuming you're on a *nix system, just add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on the first line and run it as a bash script. `bash files.txt`. Not sure of the Windows equivalent, but that should also be possible.

Comment: I'm in windows dos prompt.  making it a .bat file only executes the first line.